# Webex meeting automation

Tags: python, automation, webex

I am trying to automate the joining of Webex meeting. The code is :-

```
import subprocess
import webbrowser
import subprocess
import pyttsx3
import time
import pyautogui 
import selenium 
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome
keyboard = Controller()
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("hello , opening chrome") 
engine.runAndWait() 

subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Users\Hardik\Desktop\Google\Chrome Beta\Application\chrome.exe')  
time.sleep(20)
pyautogui.typewrite("The meet link")
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
time.sleep(20)
pyautogui.moveTo(486,586, duration = 1)
pyautogui.click(486,586)
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrlleft", "d")
time.sleep(3)
engine.say("Meeting joined ") 
engine.runAndWait()
```

can anyone suggest a way to join a particular link at a particular day (eg. wed , thurs etc.) without having to make different scripts?

Comment: A script would be welcomed gratefully,  if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the weekday() Method to find the day.

from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.today().weekday())

Now, you can proceed in your own way.

One way,
if day == "Thursday":
...enter link and do like in your code

You can define a function to avoid repeating the same for all days.
Hope it helps

Comment: And what for time ?